# Module command and differential equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I write a programma see below

```
findlsp[M_, r2_, r3_, x_, MM1_, MM2_, Smu_] := Module[{i, j, t},
  evolutionG = NDSolve[{
     M1'[t] == b1n*g1[t]^2*M1[t]/8/Pi^2, M1[tGUT] == M,
      M2'[t] == b2n*g2[t]^2*M2[t]/8/Pi^2, M2[tGUT] == r2*M,
      M3'[t] == b3n*g3[t]^2*M3[t]/8/Pi^2, M3[tGUT] == r3*M}, {M1, M2, 
     M3}, {t, tI, tGUT}] ;
  MM1[t_] := Part[Evaluate[M1[t] /. evolutionG], 1]
```

I do something wrong with the command Module?

The error come out:

> ```
> Pattern t_ appears on the right-hand side of rule 
> MM1[t_]:>(Evaluate[M1[t$1004]/. evolutionG][[1]]    
> MM2[t_]:=Evaluate[M2[<<1>>]/. evolutionG][[1]] 
> MM3[t_]:=Evaluate[ReplaceAll[<<2>>]][[1]] 
> PM11=Plot[{MM3[t$1004],MM1[t$1004],MM2[t$1004]},{t$1004,tI,tGUT}]). >>......
> ```

Thanks for your time
Demetra

Comment: No need to post two question about the same problem -- if you clarified [`(114945)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114945/what-i-make-wrong-with-module-command) people would have responded.